# WSL Python Pytest Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to write some automation tests for my Python Flask app, I need to add chromedriver and geckodriver to my path. I use WSL and I have tried adding to the PATH and it still does not work. I get this error message.

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\Users\barke\Documents\Drivers\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I think I have a problem in understanding which browser I am running as I have a firefox/chrome on both wsl and windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.